# strange freetype rendering with notosan font

Tags: freetype2

I had a some Issue of font rendering with NotosansCJK(Google Opensource font) and freetype 2
My freetype version is 2.8.1 and here is a part of my code when I make bitmap from Ft to create opengl texture.

[Rendering alphabet with freetype library]

```
bool bRender = false;
FT_Error fError;
uint uCharIndex;

if(m_tFTFace == KD_NULL)
{
    return bRender;
}

if( m_nCharFontSize != nCharFontSize )
{
    if(SetCharSize(nCharFontSize) == KD_FALSE)
    {
        return bRender;
    }
}

uCharIndex = FT_Get_Char_Index(m_tFTFace,(FT_ULong)uCharUnicode);

if(uCharIndex == 0)
{
    return bRender;
}

fError = FT_Load_Glyph(m_tFTFace,uCharIndex, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT | FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP );
if(fError)
{
    return bRender;
}

if(m_nExtraBoldthick > 0)
{
    FT_Outline_Embolden(&m_tFTFace->glyph->outline, (m_tFTFace->size->metrics.x_ppem*m_nExtraBoldthick/100)*64);
}

fError = FT_Render_Glyph(m_tFTFace->glyph,FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL);
if(fError)
{
    return bRender;
}
else
{
    bRender = KD_TRUE;
}

if( bRender == KD_TRUE )
{
    m_uRenderedUnicode = uCharUnicode;
}

return bRender;
```

[Make an alpha bitmap]

```
FT_Face pFace = m_oTtfFont.GetFontFace();

int nBitmapWidth,nBitmapHeight;
nBitmapWidth  = pFace->glyph->bitmap.width;
nBitmapHeight = pFace->glyph->bitmap.rows;

kdMemset( pBitmap->m_aBitmap, 0, sizeof(KDubyte)*32*32);

int nTX = pFace->glyph->bitmap_left + 32/2 - (pFace->glyph->advance.x>>6) ;
int nTY = 0;

int y = nBitmapHeight;

while( y-- > 0 )
{
    nTX = pFace->glyph->bitmap_left;
    if(nTX < 0)
    {
        nBitmapWidth =  pFace->glyph->bitmap.width + nTX;
        nTX = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        nBitmapWidth =  pFace->glyph->bitmap.width;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < nBitmapWidth; x++)
    {
        pBitmap->m_aBitmap[nTY][nTX] = pFace->glyph->bitmap.buffer[(y*nBitmapWidth)+x];
        nTX++;
    }
    nTY++;
}
```

Almost all of alphabets are rendering correctly but some of results are abnormal especially English if I use a character size more than 15.
all of notosancjk font has similar problem when I test it

this is the result using NotoSansCJKkr-Bold.otf and the character size is 20

[result - normal] - alphabet O

[image: Sample Image]

[result - abnormal] - alphabet V

[image: Sample Image]

I think it's a problem of freetype library or NotosanCJK font because There has no problem when I use another fonts but I'm not sure it is the real reasons.

Do anyone guess the reason of this Issue?

Thanks